# Given $x =\{1,2,3\}, y= \{4,5,6\}$ we see each member of y are greater than all members of x.

Tags: notation

Given one set x = {1,2,3} and another set y= {4,5,6}, we can safely say that all members of y are greater than all members of x.

What is the most efficient way to express this in notation (Latex)?

Comment: I think you man "greater than all members of $x$" not "greater than $x$".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm leaving my answer up *pro tem*, but I now agree with @Community that it is highly unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "set notation"? You have multiple answers that clearly take very different readings on that.

Comment: Reworded my question to remove ambiguity. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just define your own notation? $A>B$ should be unambiguous in most cases. If not, use $A\succ B$ or anything you like.

Answer (score 1):

$\min(y)>\max(x)$

If you're dealing with infinite sets, $\min$ and $\max$ might technically be not defined (e.g. there is no minimum positive real number), so it gets more complicated. $(\inf(y)>\sup(x))\rightarrow $ (all of $y$ is greater than all of $x$), but the converse it not true. Going back to the example of positive real numbers, all of them are greater than every negative real number, but the $\inf$ of positive numbers and the $\sup$ of negative numbers are both $0$.

Comment: $\inf(y)>\sup(x)$ doesn’t  cover all cases. It is possible for it to be true when $\inf(y)=\sup(x)$ and $x\cap y=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall b \in y\forall a \in x(b > a)$$ Hold down Control and hover over the formula to get a menu that will let you see what the $\LaTeX$ looks like (or just click on Edit and then cancel when you've seen enough).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard notation to compare sets memberwise. In any case, it is clear that comparing sets member by member as you want gives a lattice, so you can *define_ that for sets $A, $$ you write $A \le B$ if the above relaton holds.

To define the relation, as I understand it (sort the elememnts of both sets, and compare the resulting vectors memberwise if they have the same number of elements), formally isn't easy.